# Probability books with some "fun", recreational applications

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, book-recommendation

I know basic probability theory reasonably well. I have taken elementary courses in probability, statistics, and an introductory course in discrete stochastic processes in college a few years ago. I am also reasonably comfortable with basic mathematical foundations like linear algebra and calculus. I use statistics regularly at work.

I am looking for some probability books that shows somewhat recreational applications of probability. Some examples I have in mind are

[German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

[Secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem)

[Auditing election using hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Application_to_auditing_elections)

I have read [Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486653552) and I have read the ["Probability Problems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Probability_problems) page (there are not that many) on Wikipedia but I am interested in more. To be frank I am not looking for dry theoretical textbooks -- just something to read in spare time to entertain myself.

Comment: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/one-thousand-exercises-in-probability-9780198572213?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: I don't know any such probability books, but there are recreational math books that have some probability problems in them. E.g., Halmos, Problems for Mathematicians Young and Old, has a chapter of probability problems. There are probability problems scattered throughout Martin Gardner's books.